# What is an indexer?

Tags: c#, python, terminology, concepts, indexing

The C# docs have a [page on indexers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/), which appears to use "indexer" to refer to the construct required to enable instances of a class to be accessed via square bracket notation.

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays.

```
// Define the indexer to allow client code to use [] notation.
public T this[int i]
{
   get { return arr[i]; }
   set { arr[i] = value; }
}
```

On the other hand, the pandas docs use "indexer" in several ways. Firstly, `DataFrame` attributes such as `ix`, `loc` and `iloc` that exist to enable different kinds of indexing operation on `DataFrame` instances are called indexers themselves. For example, see [the first line in the docs for `ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

> A primarily label-location based indexer, with integer position fallback.

Yet "indexer" is also [used elsewhere](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/indexing.html) to refer to the argument passed within square brackets:

> `.iloc` is strictly integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the axis), will raise `IndexError` if an indexer is requested and it is out-of-bounds, except *`slice`* indexers which allow out-of-bounds indexing.

Both of these uses are also found [in the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1368), so this is consistent.

The [Wikipedia page for indexers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexer_%28programming%29) does not help distinguish between all of the examples above, although the page in general does seem biased to the usage in the C# docs.

> In object-oriented programming, an indexer allows instances of a particular class or struct to be indexed just like arrays.

What is an indexer? Are all of these usages correct? What am I missing?

Comment: Looks to me like "indexer" has multiple different meanings. In C#, an indexer is an indexed property whose parameter is written in between square brackets. Wikipedia's "Indexer" page is talking about C# indexers. In pandas, an indexer seems to be something else; I don't know what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no universally accepted definition of "indexer".

Each language/framework might overload the name for its own use.

As you point out, it usually has something to do with the ability to "index" a thing. But that is as far as any similarity between its uses go.

Comment: Context. Without context the word indexer could refer to the job of the guy that writes the pages in the back of the book that are titled: "Index".

Comment: @CandiedOrange Just as "computer" is guy that does calculations.

Comment: Thanks! I hoped this would not be the case as I feel that it would be useful to have a more concrete vocabulary to refer to these constructs

Comment: @Ninjakannon: That seems to be a common desire of software developers: to have a specific name for every specific thing.  If English were as precise as a programming language, then it might be a worthwhile endeavor, but it isn't.

Comment: @Ninjakannon Feel free to invent a word. Just be careful or other people will start to use it. I know, trademark it. Then other people will have to use a different word. Hey wait a minute.

Comment: @RobertHarvey & CandiedOrange I'm writing an article where I mention indexers, and I discovered that there were more shades of meaning in the uses of the term than I had realised! Now I have to be more careful to specify my meaning and its context.

Comment: @Ninjakannon I think at the root of this is that the term [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index#Computer_science) is very overloaded.  Since 'indexer' means (roughly): 'something that creates indexes', it follows that it's also overloaded.